# If there is an XML response and it is stored in a string buffer , how would I parse it?

Tags: java, xml

Which API should I use to parse XML response from a URL stored in a string buffer ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html):

```
// Given StringBuffer sb from your URL
String contextPath = "path/to/generated/jaxb/package";
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Object o = u.unmarshal(new StreamSource( new StringReader(sb.toString())));
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to process the XML.

If it is a large document and you just want to perform a one pass parse from head to tail then use a SAX API. This method will use less memory and have higher processing throughput.

If you want to manipulate the XML tree, and traverse the Nodes up and down the tree then use  a DOM API. This method requires the whole XML DOM to be in memory, but allows you to manipulate the DOM and perform XPath type queries on it.

I believe [SAXON](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) can handle both.